# Почему не работает присваивание переменной значения в lambda функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, оператор-присваивания

```
def _create_candle(self, index):
    candle = Candle(index)
    self.candles.append(candle)

    def o(response):
        candle.open = response.result

    def h(response):
        candle.high = response.result

    def l(response):
        candle.low = response.result

    def c(response):
        candle.close = response.result

    def v(response):
        candle.volume = response.result

    def t(response):
        candle.time = response.result

    self._api.send("O", lambda response: candle.open = response.result, self._ds_id, index)  # не работает
    self._api.send("H", h, self._ds_id, index)
    self._api.send("L", l, self._ds_id, index)
    self._api.send("C", c, self._ds_id, index)
    self._api.send("V", v, self._ds_id, index)
    self._api.send("T", t, self._ds_id, index)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В лямбдах нельзя присваивать элементы (**до python 3.8**, см. соседний ответ для 3.8+).

Попытки присвоить приведут к ошибке: `SyntaxError: can't assign to lambda`.

Но можно попытаться обойти ограничение, пример:

```
class Foo:
    pass

f = Foo()
f.a = 10
print(f.a)  # 10

# result = lambda x: f.a = x  # Ошибка
result = lambda x: setattr(f, 'a', x)
result(78)
print(f.a)  # 78

result('abc')
print(f.a)  # abc
```

Answer (score 5):

Вы уже в [будущем](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) - в *Питон 3.8* это *будет* возможно, хотя с маленькой разницей - `:=` вместо `=` и с добавленными скобками:

```
self._api.send("O", lambda response: (candle.open := response.result), self._ds_id, index)  # будет работать
```

Но *затем* в lambda функциях ожидается в качестве значения только *выражение*, а не *команда присваивания*.

(Вы вероятно знаете C/C++, где это возможно а где присваивание само считается выражением.)